# Android cannot serialize byte[] recieved from compressed BMP

Tags: android, web-services, serialization, bitmap, android-ksoap2

**The code**

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
byte[] raw = out.toByteArray();
PassToWebservice(raw); //error

PassToWebservice(byte[] ba)
{
   SoapObject envelope...
   envelope.addProperty("base64bytes", ba);
   ...
   transport.call(ACTION, envelope);
   envelope.getResponse() //error: IOException cannot serialize...
}
```

**The problem**
When I pass the compressed image to my webservice, I get a runtimeexception that says "cannot serialize [B@47bcb6c8..." Something is not apparent to me, can anyone see why the above (psuedo) code does not work? If it helps, on the webservice server side, the exception seems to be happening when the server writes the passed bytes to a file (using .Net IO.File.WriteAllBytes)

**Stack trace**
[image]

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question. The exception message suggests it's failing to serialize the byte[], i.e. your bytes aren't reaching the server. Can you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: It looks like its inflating the request and hasn't been sent out yet. I have the Jar for ksoap2 and not the source, so I cant be too certain. It might be beneficial to find the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to do this:

```
MarshalBase64 marshal;
marshal.register(envelope);
```

Comment: @Nital I'm sorry this question was quite awhile ago, I dont understand.

Answer (score 0):

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

```
        new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);   // this is will over Cannot serialize: [B@f034108 

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        //Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        //Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAPACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```